# Change Image with type writing text effect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to change the image after every line is typed out. The example shows only 2 lines and 2 images but there would be many lines and images.

Image must change once the line content changes.

How can I go about this?

**JSDiffle: https://jsfiddle.net/13ujowkL/**

HTML

```
  <div class="output" id="output">
    <h1 class="cursor"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4Y054xz3/video-1.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/8jt43HcM/video-2.jpg">
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.cursor::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: #00b69d;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
h1.cursor::after {
  height: 24px;
  width: 13px;
}
p.cursor::after {
  height: 13px;
  width: 6px;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  49% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

jQuery

```
// values to keep track of the number of letters typed, which quote to use. etc. Don't change these values.
var i = 0,
    a = 0,
    isBackspacing = false,
    isParagraph = false;

// Typerwrite text content. Use a pipe to indicate the start of the second line "|".  
var textArray = [
  "This line would show video-1.jpg", 
  "And this would show video-2.jpg"
];

// Speed (in milliseconds) of typing.
var speedForward = 100, //Typing Speed
    speedWait = 1000, // Wait between typing and backspacing
    speedBetweenLines = 1000, //Wait between first and second lines
    speedBackspace = 25; //Backspace Speed

//Run the loop
typeWriter("output", textArray);

function typeWriter(id, ar) {
  var element = $("#" + id),
      aString = ar[a],
      eHeader = element.children("h1"), //Header element
      eParagraph = element.children("p"); //Subheader element

  // Determine if animation should be typing or backspacing
  if (!isBackspacing) {

    // If full string hasn't yet been typed out, continue typing
    if (i < aString.length) {

      // If character about to be typed is a pipe, switch to second line and continue.
      if (aString.charAt(i) == "|") {
        isParagraph = true;
        eHeader.removeClass("cursor");
        eParagraph.addClass("cursor");
        i++;
        setTimeout(function(){ typeWriter(id, ar); }, speedBetweenLines);

      // If character isn't a pipe, continue typing.
      } else {
        // Type header or subheader depending on whether pipe has been detected
        if (!isParagraph) {
          eHeader.text(eHeader.text() + aString.charAt(i));
        } else {
          eParagraph.text(eParagraph.text() + aString.charAt(i));
        }
        i++;
        setTimeout(function(){ typeWriter(id, ar); }, speedForward);
      }

    // If full string has been typed, switch to backspace mode.
    } else if (i == aString.length) {

      isBackspacing = true;
      setTimeout(function(){ typeWriter(id, ar); }, speedWait);

    }

  // If backspacing is enabled
  } else {

    // If either the header or the paragraph still has text, continue backspacing
    if (eHeader.text().length > 0 || eParagraph.text().length > 0) {

      // If paragraph still has text, continue erasing, otherwise switch to the header.
      if (eParagraph.text().length > 0) {
        eParagraph.text(eParagraph.text().substring(0, eParagraph.text().length - 1));
      } else if (eHeader.text().length > 0) {
        eParagraph.removeClass("cursor");
        eHeader.addClass("cursor");
        eHeader.text(eHeader.text().substring(0, eHeader.text().length - 1));
      }
      setTimeout(function(){ typeWriter(id, ar); }, speedBackspace);

    // If neither head or paragraph still has text, switch to next quote in array and start typing.
    } else { 

      isBackspacing = false;
      i = 0;
      isParagraph = false;
      a = (a + 1) % ar.length; //Moves to next position in array, always looping back to 0
      setTimeout(function(){ typeWriter(id, ar); }, 50);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've modified your code please check, https://jsbin.com/mebanajufo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: The code isn't working. The first image is to be shown when the first line is shown and disappear when it disappears. The second image shows when the second line starts and disappear when it finishes and show the first image again as the text is typed out. And it goes in the loop. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, try this https://jsbin.com/valayohota/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `images` object,

```
var images = {
  0: { 
  "urls": [
     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d_T5P-zIIAs/maxresdefault.jpg",
     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg"
  ]},
  1: {
  "urls": [
     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg",
     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d_T5P-zIIAs/maxresdefault.jpg"
  ]},
  2: { 
    "urls": [
     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d_T5P-zIIAs/maxresdefault.jpg",
     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg"
  ]}
}
```

Then change images using function,

```
function changeImage(number) {
  var imagesArr = [];
  images[number].urls.forEach(function(url){
    imagesArr.push('<img src="'+ url +'">');
  });

  $('.images').html(imagesArr);
}
```

You need to call this function in last `else` block,

```
// If neither head or paragraph still has text, switch to next quote in array and start typing.
} else {
   changeImage(a);
}
```

Working sample: https://jsbin.com/valayohota/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: The working example isn't updated I believe and so it's not working.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, try this https://jsbin.com/valayohota/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This is beyond perfection. Thank you so much. Will add some animation effect and it will be good to go. Thank you once again :)